# Checking a html date input is after a given date

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with a html datetime-local input type. When the form is submitted how can I check to see if the date entered is after the current time.

I'd prefer to do this using pure javascript.

The issue if comparing dates is that the form datetime-local element returns doesn't match the format from new Date() or new Date().toISOString()

Format from form element: 2014-09-27T00:00
Format from new Date(): 2014-09-03T15:45:45.027Z

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you create a demo of your code using jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: @Elliott Shafii does solution help you

Comment: I've added an update about the format of the date when comparing. I'm using Google Apps Script (which is technically javascript) so I can't post a jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

like below

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="event_date" class="datepicker">


 <script>   
    var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var now = new Date();
    if (selectedDate < now) {
      // selected date is in the past
    }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1996-12-19T16:39:57 is the format in which datetime-local returns the time. You can take the date and use it as you like. Please provide a jsfiddle if you need something more specific.